# ReactJS sort by Asc/Desc not rendering sorted list from nested component

Tags: reactjs, sorting

## Project Overview

I am currently learning ReactJS and am creating a Pokedex app that allows the user to sort Pokemon objects by specific properties (name, type, hp, etc). The end product should have a search input to filter by pokemon name, a drop-down selector for sort criteria, and buttons for sort Ascend and sort Descend. State being tracked is  searchQuery, sortBy, sortSelected, and pokeData(my data file).

Full code can be viewed here: https://github.com/julianne-vela/Pokedex-React/tree/dev

***File Structure:*** SearchPage.js > SideBar.js > SortMenu.js

### Problem

---

onClick button in SortMenu is not rendering sorted Pokemon list.

**Expected Result**: Click Asc/Desc button in SortMenu -> Pokemon list renders in sorted order based on criteria selected in drop-down and Asc/Desc button clicked.

**Actual Result**: Drop-down is updating state with correct sort criteria selected but button is not triggering any action when clicked.

### What I've tried

---

*Using destructured props throughout project*

```
const {
    sortBy,
    sortSelected,
} = this.state
```

Currently passing the following props from SearchPage.js to child SideBar.js:

```
sortByValues={sortBy} // Array of sort criteria options stored in state
sortSelected={sortSelected} // Currently selected sort criteria from drop-down
handleSortSelected={this.handleSortSelected} // event handler to update state with currently selected sort criteria
sortAsc={this.sortAsc} // function to trigger Asc sort onClick
sortDesc={this.sortDesc} // function to trigger Asc sort onClick
```

---

#### SortMenu.js Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SortMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            sortByValues,
            handleSortSelected,
            sortAsc,
            sortDesc,
        } = this.props

        const options = sortByValues.map(option => <option value={option} key={option}>{option}</option>)

        return (
            <aside>
                {/* DropDown Sort By */}
                <select className='dropdown'
                    onChange={handleSortSelected}>
                    {options}
                </select>

                {/* Sort Ascending/Descending Buttons */}
                <button className='sortBtn' value='ascending' onClick={sortAsc}>Ascending</button>
                <button className='sortBtn' value='descending' onClick={sortDesc}>Descending</button>

            </aside >
        )
    }
}
```

---

I feel it's important to note that we are using strictly class components and therefore are not using constructor(props) in this project. Instead, I am using arrow functions throughout to implicitly bind this where needed.

**To reiterate my goal:** I need to dynamically render the pokemon list based on the sort criteria selected in the drop-down list as well as the ascend/descend button clicked. The list should update onClick.

I have been working on this for 3 days and have gone through so many iterations of sort functions that I can't even see straight anymore. I'm thinking this might be a simple over-sight due to the sheer amount of code I'm writing as well as the fact that this is a new language (I'm already proficient in Vanilla JS).

Any guidance here would be GREATLY appreciated as I'm really at a wall at this point. I don't know what else to try in order to render the sorted list.

#### Update

Also, would it be easier if I were to create a toggle button instead of two separate buttons for Asc/Desc?

Thank you!

#### Update 2

Currently I am rendering my pokemon objects in a module component that I'm calling within the SearchPage.js component. Here is the code for the Pokemon List:

```
export default class PokemonList extends Component {


    render() {
        const { filteredPokemon } = this.props

        return (
            <content className='pokemon-list float'>
                {filteredPokemon.map(pokeObject =>
                    <PokeItem
                        key={pokeObject._id}
                        pokeImage={pokeObject.url_image}
                        pokeName={capFirstLetter(pokeObject.pokemon)}
                        pokeType={capFirstLetter(pokeObject.type_1)}
                        pokeHp={pokeObject.hp}
                        pokeAtt={pokeObject.attack}
                        pokeDef={pokeObject.defense}
                    />)}
            </content>
        );
    }
}
```

This is pulling the filtered pokemon from my filter method on SearchPage.js:

```
const filteredList = pokeData.filter(pokeObject => {
            return pokeObject['pokemon'].includes(this.state.searchQuery) || pokeObject['type_1'].includes(tFilterSelected);
        });
```

To sort the items, I'm using two separate arrow functions. These are housed in the first section of the SearchPage.js component (outside of render and return):

```
sortAsc = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            this.state.pokeData.sort((a, b) => (a[this.state.sortSelected] - b[this.state.sortSelected]))
        })
    }

    sortDesc = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            this.state.pokeData.sort((a, b) => (b[this.state.sortSelected] - a[this.state.sortSelected]))
        })
    }
```

#### Update 3

Added project to CodeSandbox. Can view here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pokedex-react-crflb

Comment: Can you include how you are rendering your sorted items?

Comment: @DrewReese I think I included what you were asking. Let me know if that doesn't make it clear or if I'm missing anything else. Thanks!

Comment: @Julianne Can you share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) URL with your code?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I've never used that platform before but that is really cool! I've added the CodeSandbox URL to my post.

Comment: @Julianne Let me take a look.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Awesome! Thank you! Sorry if my code is a bit messy and scattered. It's a little hectic while I'm working stuff out and then I'm able to get it cleaned up much more, lol.

Comment: @Julianne No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparator function that subtracts the arguments would work fine for sorting numbers but would fail on strings since it would return `NaN`.

```js
sortAsc = () => {
  const { pokeData, sortSelected } = this.state
  this.setState({
    pokeData: [...pokeData].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[sortSelected] > b[sortSelected]) {
        return 1
      }

      if (a[sortSelected] < b[sortSelected]) {
        return -1
      }

      return 0
    })
  })
}

sortDesc = () => {
  const { pokeData, sortSelected } = this.state
  this.setState({
    pokeData: [...pokeData].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[sortSelected] > b[sortSelected]) {
        return -1
      }

      if (a[sortSelected] < b[sortSelected]) {
        return 1
      }

      return 0
    })
  })
}
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pokedex-react-3dwrc)

Comment: Oh my word! Thank you so so so so so much! I've been wracking my brain over this for SO long and I was SOOOO CLOSE BEFORE! I had basically this exact function written out before but I wasn't using the key:value syntax so it wasn't working! I appreciate you so much! Thank you again!